How to solve a system of nonlinear equations with power-law terms
I have a research problem to solve the system like the following equations：
$$
\begin{aligned}
D_{11} &= M_{11}^1 \cdot \left(A_1 S_1 + B_1 S_2 + C_1 S_3 \right)^{\frac{1}{n}} 
     + M_{11}^2 \cdot \left(A_2 S_1 + B_2 S_2 + C_2 S_3 \right)^{\frac{1}{n}} 
     + M_{11}^3 \cdot \left(A_3 S_1 + B_3 S_2 + C_3 S_3 \right)^{\frac{1}{n}} +..., \\
D_{22} &= M_{22}^1 \cdot \left(A_1 S_1 + B_1 S_2 + C_1 S_3 \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}  
     + M_{22}^2 \cdot \left(A_2 S_1 + B_2 S_2 + C_2 S_3 \right)^{\frac{1}{n}} 
     + M_{22}^3 \cdot \left(A_3 S_1 + B_3 S_2 + C_3 S_3 \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}+..., \\
D_{33} &= M_{33}^1 \cdot \left(A_1 S_1 + B_1 S_2 + C_1 S_3 \right)^{\frac{1}{n}} 
     + M_{33}^2 \cdot \left(A_2 S_1 + B_2 S_2 + C_2 S_3 \right)^{\frac{1}{n}} 
     + M_{33}^3 \cdot \left(A_3 S_1 + B_3 S_2 + C_3 S_3 \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}+...
\end{aligned}
$$
D_ij is a 3x3 matrix consist of 9 known values, corresponding to defomation tensor of loading sample.
A_k, B_k, C_k are known constants where the variable values k correspond the activative system, and there are 12 system, so i = 1, 2, 3, ...12.
M^k is a 3x3 matrix, and k correspond to 12 activate system, so k = 1,2,3 ...12, and M^k_ij is the component of the corresponding matrix, and All the components of M^k_ij are known values.
n is known constant.
1.)I want to solve for S1 S2 S3. I want to find the method to solve this system. Can I ask for the keyword for find the method？
2.)As I know it can use Approximation method to find the numerical solution. Does it is possible to find the analytical solution of nonlinear system？

Start by simplifying. Set $x_1 := (A_1S_1 + B_1S_2+C_1S_3)^{1/n}$, etc.

Couldn’t you use Newton’s method?

@A rural reader: I'm sorry i didn't clarify my question specifically, because Ai Bi Ci correspond the 12 activated system, so if i use xi = (AiS1+BiS2+CiS3), there will be 12 variable. and I can only write at most 5 equations In my situation.

@mhdadk: actually i use vpasolve function in matlab to solve this problem, but it can't solve the equation, so now i just start to study the relative theorem. Thanks for your comment, i'll try it.

MSE is not a "do my homework/work for me" site. Posts like this (e.g. "PSQs") are in poor taste, & often downvoted & closed; we expect users to put in effort! If you want meaningful help, [edit] your post to add relevant context (more), e.g. relevant definitions, your work/attempts, the problem's source, where specifically you're stuck, what you do/don't understand & have learned recently, & so on. If needed: this is useful for formatting LaTeX, & Approach0 helps find past questions.
